# Protect streamed videos

Tags: html, video, flash, streaming

I am for html5/flash video player to play videos (stream) on a website and we want to protect our material as much as we can. any suggestions ?

**Edit**
We want it to limit the download of the video and re-sharing it in other ways

Comment: protect it from what?

Comment: Which kind of a protection do you need for your videos? Do you mind providing a little more details? Please?

Answer (score 1):

**Watermark it.** There is no way to stop someone from saving locally anything they see because once it is seen, it is on their machine, even if not all at once.

The best way to protect your content is to transform it into an advertisement for your site. A number of sites do this and every few seconds you see scrolling text that says  *Video produced by myvideos.com* or something similar. The amount of work required to remove such thing is enormous. Just make sure it happens during the video and only at the credits because someone can just edit it out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I know that we can't completely stop users from saving the videos because in the worst case scenario the user can record it locally but we want to raise the bar. and of course we are going to watermark our videos.